# Inner/nested class - difference between private and public

Tags: c++

i have inner nested class, which is private:

```
   class Client{
   private:
      class Inner;
      Inner *i;
```

What would happen exactly, if I would make class Inner public and Inner *i would stay private? What would happen, and what affect would it have when it comes to program execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following case usage:

```
class Client
{
private:
    class Inner {};
    Inner *i;

    class Inner2 {};
public:
    class Inner3 {};
    Inner3 *j;

public:
    Inner2 *k;
};

void main()
{
    Client c;

    c.i = nullptr; //error: you cant access the private members

    c.j = nullptr; //ok: member is public
    c.k = nullptr; //ok: same here, member is public, even if it's type is private

    Client::Inner3 i3;//ok: to declare since Inner3 is declared public

    Client::Inner2 i3;//error: can't access private members of type declarations

}
```

Other than this the execution of the program is not affected in any case by private/public or protected.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `Client::Inner` public, its **name** becomes accessible. It has no effect on the accessibility of `i`;

```
class Client{
public:
    class Public;
private:
    class Private;
    Public a;
    Private b;
};

int main()
{
    Client::Public a;
    Client::Private b; // error

    Client c;
    c.a;  // error
    c.b;  // error
}
```